# Remove printer from the list permenantly

Tags: printing, 14.04

I want to remove some printers which I see in system settings->printers section. I edited the file /etc/cups/printer.conf and it removes it temporarily, but when I reboot the machine it seems that it adds the printers automatically from the network. How can I avoid this/ remove them permanently?
I tried with sudo lpadmin -x  as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Disable Cups automatic remote printer detection:

To disable it i'd to type simply

```
sudo cupsctl --no-remote-printers
```

or to edit the

```
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

and set

```
Browsing Off
```

Comment: I had Browsing Off in that file. and I did comment it. But after reboot, I did not see any printer in my list. What I want is, not all the printers to show in my list only the ones which I want.

Comment: Same issue here. Browsing is off, but still all the printers show up.